# React Native Modal background doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, react-native-modal

Im using [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal)

This was my modal

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
..
....
..
   <Modal
      visible={modalVisible} //this one was the issue (should be isVisible)
      animationType={'slide'}
      swipeDirection="down"
      transparent={true}
      onRequestClose={() => closeModal()}
      onSwipeComplete={() => closeModal()}
      style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end', margin: 0}}
    >
    </Modal>
```

So as you can see, my idea was to open it half way and slide it down to close

My problem was that it was acting weird, the modal wasn't updating properly, sometimes the modal opened way less than it was supposed to

Comment: what is the meaning of line -

"my idea was to open it half way "  ??

Comment: @MukulSharma i was referring to something like *Bottom Half*  in this gif https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/raw/master/.github/images/example-modal.gif . But to go as far as the middle screen

Comment: @MukulSharma I already figured it out tho, I googled it but couldn´t find an answer so I just posted the question + answer for someone else to find it faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [the documentation](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal#the-modal-background-doesnt-animate-properly) and common problems:

The solution was to change the **visible** prop to isVisible

```
isVisible={modalVisible}
```